# Error in SelBlocks extension for Selenium IDE - sel-blocks.js

Tags: selenium-ide

I´ve searched for this and haven´t found an answer, but anyway if it is already answered somewhere, copy the link for me please.

My problem is that i´m using the extension selblocks for Selenium IDE and when i open my test case and try to run it, i get the following error:
"In chrome://selblocks/content/extensions/sel-blocks.js @289: ReferenceError: FatalError is not defined"

I look for the file sel-blocks.js and it´s nowhere to be found, so i can´t even try to fix the error. I also think it is not a problem of my test case because it is still a really simple test case, tho maybe it is not correct, cause i'm new to Selenium (anyway i will put it here just in case it is indeed a problem of my testcase...).
(Can't post a screenshot, don't have enough reputation points, so html will have to do)

```
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>http://test.projects.local/plans</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>javascript{elementExists(&quot;link=&quot;.${i})}</td>
  <td>elemexist</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>while</td>
  <td>elemexist</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>click</td>
  <td>link=${i}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>${i}++</td>
  <td>i</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>javascript{elementExists(&quot;link=&quot;.${i})}</td>
  <td>elemexist</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>endWhile</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this or where to find this file?

EDITED: I changed the test case so i don't need to use Selblocks, but anyway, i'm interested in knowing where is this file if anyone knows, to avoid future problems or just to know how this extension works.

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FatalError message masks information about the real problem because of an error handling bug in older versions of SelBlocks. Please upgrade.

When I run this script with SelBlocks 1.3, there is an error with the javascript expression, which seems to be mising a colon: javascript:{$e("link=".${i})}

EDIT:

BTW, the following should accomplish the same thing:

```
for|i=0; elementExists("link="+i); i++
  click|link=${i}
endFor
```

This works because SelBlocks expressions are javascript, and are evaluated with Selenium's variables in-scope. In this example, `i` is local to the for loop. But `i` is still a Selenium variable, which is why `${i}` can be used in any Selenium command inside the loop.

*Note - that prior to SelBlocks 2.0, for loops did not automatically initialize their loop variable(s) unless declared in the `Value` argument.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working with Selblocks now. Indeed the problem was in the missing ":".